# Is it possible to pass cid field in template?

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller, underscore.js, template-engine, underscore.js-templating

I have a view that have template that looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
   <div id="<%=cid=>"></div>
   <label><%= label %></label>
   <input type="text" id="search_input" />
   <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
</script>
```

And i need to render this template using model data, so I do the following:

```
render: function () {
   var template = _.template( $("#template").html(), this.model.toJSON());
   this.$el.html( template );
   return this;
}
```

But unfortunately this.model.toJSON() doesn't pass cid (clientId) to my template. May you explain how could I get access to cid in my template and how do you handle this thing?

Answer (score 7):

`toJSON` simply clones `attributes` array. That's why there's no cid. If you need exactly **cid** from the model, you may mix it in the template object:

```
var templateData = _.extend(this.model.toJSON(), { cid: this.model.cid });
var template = _.template( $("#template").html(), templateData);
```

But if you need a just unique ID for your `div` - I would recommend to use [_.uniqueId()](http://lodash.com/docs#uniqueId)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can override the `toJSON()` method of the `Backbone.Model` class, as follow :

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name:''
    },
    toJSON: function() {
       var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.apply(this, arguments);
       json.cid = this.cid;
       return json;
    }
});

var PersonItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
     tmpl:'<div data-cid="<%=cid%>"><%=name%></div>',
     render: function () {
         var template = _.template( this.tmpl)(this.model.toJSON());
         this.$el.html( template );
         return this;
     }
});
var person =  new Person({name:'John'})
var personItemView = new PersonItemView({model:person});
personItemView.render().$el.appendTo('body');
```

And the result just like this :

```
<div><div data-cid="c8">John</div></div>
```

So , if you want to get the view according the model ,you can

```
var cid = person.cid ;
var $personItem = $('[data-cid="+ cid +"]').parent();
```

With the `cid` , you can build the connection between model and view .